# Hive Vertex failed: killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I was querying a table,a simple count(*) and received the following error:

```
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1486982569467_0809_3_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1486982569467_0809_3_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: table_name initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1486982569467_0809_3_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:155)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$BISplitStrategy.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1161)
    ... 15 more
```

Query : select count(*) from table_name;

Not sure whats the issue as I have a job setup that populates this table daily. But it stopped populating a couple of days back.

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: added the query to the post.

Comment: I mean your code not the query this soooo small part of your code, post the part which make this problem :)

Comment: the problem is not in your query it is in your code

Comment: I received this error when I ran the above query on hive.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because your table is created to read an orc file but the actual file in the table location is in some other format like text. It is expecting ORC files but receiving something else.